# The modal form is closed or the page refreshes when you click the axios post delete data command

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, bootstrap-modal, laravel-8

How to apply axios to reload the page after clicking the bootstrap form modal button with the following code:

Delete data function code:

```js
deleteData(id) {
    // console.log(id)
    // this.book = book;
    const self = this;
    this.actionUrl = '{{ url('
    books ') }}' + '/' + id;
    if (confirm("Anda yakin?!")) {
        axios.post(this.actionUrl, {
            _method: 'DELETE'
        }).then(response => {
            **
            location.reload(); **
        });

    }
}
```

Bootstrap modal form:

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-default" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
   aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Form Data Modal</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" :action="actionUrl" autocomplete="off">
               @csrf
               <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" v-if="editStatus">
               <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">ISBN:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="isbn" :value="book.isbn">
               </div>
               <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Judul:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" :value="book.title">
               </div>
               <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Tahun:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="year" :value="book.year">
               </div>
               <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Publisher:</label>
                  <select name="publisher_id" class="form-control">
                     @foreach ($publisher_data as $publishers)
                     <option :selected="book.publisher_id == {{ $publishers->id }}"
                        value="{{ $publishers->id }}">
                        {{ $publishers->name }}
                     </option>
                     @endforeach
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Author:</label>
                  <select name="author_id" class="form-control">
                     @foreach ($author_data as $authors)
                     <option :selected="book.author_id == {{ $authors->id }}"
                        value="{{ $authors->id }}">
                        {{ $authors->name }}
                     </option>
                     @endforeach
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Catalog:</label>
                  <select name="catalog_id" class="form-control">
                     @foreach ($catalog_data as $catalogs)
                     <option :selected="book.catalog_id" value="{{ $catalogs->id }}">
                        {{ $catalogs->name }}
                     </option>
                     @endforeach
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Qty:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="qty" :value="book.qty">
               </div>
               <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Harga Pinjam:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" :value="book.price">
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                  **<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" v-if="editStatus"
                     v-on:click="deleteData(book)">Delete</button>**
                  {{-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" v-if="editStatus"
                     v-on:click="editData(book.id)">
                  Edit Changes</button> --}}
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" v-if="addDataButton"
                     v-on:click="editData(book)">
                  Save Changes</button>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using the method, the location.reload() function can't reload the page or refresh the page, and the bootstrap modal form is still there can't exit the bootstrap modal form?

Comment: What's your problem? You wanna close modal after page reloading or form doesn't work?

Comment: When axios appears a pop up window opens, click ok then function location.reload(); work. It doesn't work at all.

Comment: I have a feeling you are probably throwing an error in your axios request. You should try using a catch in your request. The error I believe is you are passing a book object rather than the book.id